# getelementbyid via msexcel vba object required 424

Tags: vba, excel-2010, getelementbyid

I have been struggling to get the getelementbyid (or name) code working. What I want to do is submit login details without using sendkeys. Probably is just a matter of not understanding the website. I can view the element by

MsgBox (Mid(ObjIE.Document.frames(1).Document.body.outerHTML, 1800, 1000))

which shows id= userName and name = userName. But when I try to getelementbyid it comes up with an object required error, as if its not there.

Comment: I believe its bcoz the elements are arranged inside the frames. Is it possible for you to share the link ?

Comment: you can refer this [link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40649)

Comment: Yes, I've spent a lot of time trying to get around those frames, but just can't seem to get anything to work. Website is here: http://fieldwork.genesisenergy.co.nz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

Instead of this URL http://fieldwork.genesisenergy.co.nz/

I am directly navigating to below frame src

```
<frame name="Login" src="LoginGenesis.aspx?bgColor=FFFFFF&trimColor=FF6600" frameBorder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="auto">
```

```
  Sub Website()

    Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, UserName As Object, Password As Object, strCode As String


    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True
   ' IE.navigate "http://fieldwork.genesisenergy.co.nz/"

      IE.navigate "http://fieldwork.genesisenergy.co.nz/LoginGenesis.aspx?bgColor=FFFFFF&trimColor=FF6600"

        Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set Doc = IE.document

        Set UserName = Doc.getelementbyid("userName")
        UserName.Value = "santosh"


        Set Password = Doc.getelementbyid("userPassword")
        Password.Value = "santosh@123"


       Set btnLogin = Doc.getelementbyid("loginUser")
        btnLogin.Click
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking the time to write all that out. It works perfectly. It wouldn't have occurred to me to navigate to the frame itself so you've saved me many hours of frustration!

Comment: Just one last thing. When I try this with a legit user it trips up after hitting the submit key and comes back with this error: 

'window.parent.frames.1.location' is null or not an object
Line: 41
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: http://fieldwork.genesisenergy.co.nz/LoginGenesis.aspx?bgColor=FFFFFF&trimColor=FF6600

Any ideas?

Comment: @user2473828 Once you are logged in try to redirect to url  http://fieldwork.genesisenergy.co.nz   . Even i will need the user id to see whats happening after hitting the submit key.

Comment: I've tried that but it has a habit of refreshing the page and losing the data. Can you log into test: http://fieldworktest.genesisenergy.co.nz with the user and pass as per your code (drop the @)

Comment: @user2473828 I am not able to get into site. Login santosh password santosh123 seems not working.

Comment: are you using the second link that contains "test?